# How can we call the quantity $\sup\{|a-b|: a\in A \text{ and } b\in B\}$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets

Tags: analysis

How can we call the quantity $\sup\{|a-b|: a\in A, b\in B\}$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets

Comment: Perhaps it's maximum distance between sets $A$ and $B$?

Comment: We could call it Bill.  As $|a-b|$ is often referred to as the distance between point this is the supremum of distances between points of the set.  Is there any reason we need to call it anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this the lenticular diameter of the two sets, by appealing to the geometric case of compact sets belonging to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

It should be noted that this is very closely realted to, but not quite the same as, the diameter of the union of the two sets.